# JQuery - Turning event handler off and then back on

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having a bit of trouble figuring out how to turn an event handler back on.

I'm trying to stop the function from executing multiple times before the animation is finished.

Here's a Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/MkmnW/1/

Here's my code:

```
$("#buttons a").click(function () {

    $('a').off();

    //  Remove class from current active
    $("#buttons a").removeClass('active');

    //  Change class on clicked button
    $(this).addClass("active");

    // Hide Non-Clicked Content
    $(".main_content").fadeOut("fast");


    $("#content_container").slideUp("slow");

    //  Find Selected
    var selected = $(this).attr("href");

    //  Show Selected

    $("#content_container").slideDown("slow", function () {
        $(selected).fadeIn("slow");
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: I wouldn't do that, it might be confusing for the user. Instead, abort the current animation. Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/stop/.

Comment: @Malk: Works fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: Yeah working for me in Chrome too.

Hmm, Felix, it's a bit of a UX conundrum I guess.

I just can't get the click handler to switch back on, or rather, I don't know how to or at what point to.

Comment: My bad. I didn't notice the first click I guess. I see now the event is being removed for other clicks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your example correctly you want to prevent the animation from running multiple times by removing the event.

If your removing the event you will not be able to click it again unless you attach your event again.

Here's an example based on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/MkmnW/4/

```
$(document).ready(function () {


$("#buttons a").click(function () {
    $('a').off("click");
    clickMenu(this);

    return false;
});

function clickMenu(el){
    //  Remove class from current active
    $("#buttons a").removeClass('active');

    //  Change class on clicked button
    $(el).addClass("active");

    // Hide Non-Clicked Content
    $(".main_content").fadeOut("fast");


    $("#content_container").slideUp("slow");

    //  Find Selected
    var selected = $(this).attr("href");

    //  Show Selected

     $("#content_container").slideDown("slow", function () {
        $(selected).fadeIn("slow");

        $("#buttons a").click(function () {
            $('a').off("click");
            clickMenu(this);

            return false;
        });             
    });       
}
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Just need to change the 'this' in the 'selected' variable declaration to 'el', then it works perfeclty.

Also, I'm kinda confused by the function, is it recursion? I get how it works but I start to get intimidated when functions call themselves!

Comment: Your welcome Tom. Its not actually recursion I think, you remove the onclick event when you click the a tag. So you have to put the click event back on so you can actually click a different button, to do this I moved your code into a function so you can bind the click when the slidedown animation is done. You can test this by removed the 2nd onclick assignment, if you do the 2nd click will not trigger an animation :)

Answer (score 0):

You can `$(element).unbind('click');` for unbinding click events. The same with all the other types of events.

Then, you could bind them again with `$(element).bind('click', function(evt) { ... });`

In the case of animations, you can `$(element).click(function(evt) { $(this).stop().fadeOut("fast").whatever... });`

Comment: `bind`/`unbind` are pretty old and superseeded. Use `on`/`off`.

Comment: True. I'm just used to them! :)

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to use on/off, I just don't get how to implement .on to switch it back on

Comment: It's the same syntax from bind. $(element).on('click', function(evt) { ... }); and $(element).off('click');